# How to synchronously read from a ReadStream in node

Tags: node.js, utf-8, synchronous

I am trying to read UTF-8 text from a file in a memory and time efficient way. There are two ways to read directly from a file synchronously:

- `fs.readFileSync` will read the entire file and return a buffer containing the file's entire contents
- `fs.readSync` will read a set amount of bytes from a file and return a buffer containing just those contents

I initially just used `fs.readFileSync` because it's easiest, but I'd like to be able to efficiently handle potentially large files by only reading in chunks of text at a time. So I started using `fs.readSync` instead. But then I realized that `fs.readSync` doesn't handle UTF-8 decoding. UTF-8 is simple, so I could whip up some logic to manually decode it, but Node already has services for that, so I'd like to avoid that if possible.

I noticed `fs.createReadStream`, which returns a `ReadStream` that can be used for exactly this purpose, but unfortunately it seems to only be available in an asynchronous mode of operation.

Is there a way to read from a `ReadStream` in a synchronous way? I have a massive stack built on top of this already, and I'd rather not have to refactor it to be asynchronous.

Comment: streams are async.  Can't change that.  You could, of course, get the file handle from the stream and read from it synchronously with `readSync()`, but that would not be using the stream's interface at all and would not be any better than what you've already tried.

Comment: I'm guessing that the issue with encoding and `readSync()` is that an abitrary read of bytes from  a file has no way of knowing the alignment of multi-byte characters so no proper way to interpret what is read via UTF-8 encoding.  A stream, on the other hand, or `fs.readFileSync()` starts from the beginning of the file so it can guarantee alignment.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the problem. Basically I'm looking for a way to read individually decoded characters from a file, but synchronously. Like I said, I could just implement the decoding logic myself as a layer over `readSync`, which I am prepared to do, but I was curious if something like this is already possible out of the box in Node.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the `string_decoder` module, which handles all that UTF-8 decoding logic I was worried I'd have to write. At this point, it seems like a no-brainer to use this on top of `fs.readSync` to get the synchronous behavior I was looking for.

You basically just keep feeding bytes to it, and as it is able to successfully decode characters, it will emit them. The [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/string_decoder.html) is sufficient at describing how it works.